# How to set permission on folder using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, acl, fileserver

i am trying to write a script which adds"CreatorOwner" permission to profile$ folders on all file servers;

i.e , add "CreatorOwner" permissions to "\FileServer\Profile$"

can anybody tell me whats the command and syntax for it?

Please do ask if any questions.

Comment: This link should help you accomplish what you need:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder.aspx

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I am curious ,just any specific reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is using WMI and UNC paths.

```
$AccessRule = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("CREATOR OWNER","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","Allow")
$profileshare = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName fileserver -Filter "name = 'profile$'"
$driveletter, $path = $profileshare.path
$path = $path.TrimStart("\")
$ACL = Get-Acl "\\fileserver\$driveletter`$\$path"
$ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl \\fileserver\$driveletter`$\$path -AclObject $ACL
```

Now if you have a list of server names you could do the following:

```
$servers = @("fileserver1","fileserver2","fileserver3")
$AccessRule = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("CREATOR OWNER","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","Allow")
$servers | % {
$profileshare = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName $_ -Filter "name = 'profile$'"
$driveletter, $path = $profileshare.path
$path = $path.TrimStart("\")
$ACL = Get-Acl "\\$_\$driveletter`$\$path"
$ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl \\$_\$driveletter`$\$path -AclObject $ACL
}
```

Comment: What about sample folder permisions over riding the original permissions of key dir Profile$? I just want to add CreatorOwner ACL to currectly existing Profile$ dirs; if i copy samplefolder permissions to profile$ wont it be overrided and cause multiple problems?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
#Change the CSV file path

$Permissions = Import-Csv C:\Test.CSV -delimiter '|'
ForEach ($line in $Permissions)
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, 
ObjectInherit"

$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None" 

$acl = Get-Acl $line.Path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain users", "Read", $inherit, $propagation, "Allow")

#Adding the Rule
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessrule)

#Setting the Change
Set-Acl $line.Path $acl
```

What the CSV file looks Like

\SRV01\Folder1\Folder2 etc.

Comment: hi but this is wiping out all the existing ACLs in the target folder. I do not want to wipe out existing